# 7 - 8 dynamic routes

Tags: angular, dynamic, routes, angular7, angular8

I have an Angular app which should be able to create new routes depending on users. Let's say user 'johndoe' registers, then the app should create a route: `domain/johndoe`.

Of course the `/johndoe` route should be provided with some info concerning the particular user ( like name, image etc.).

I am using Google Cloud Hosting and Firestore as back-end solutions, and my progress so far was to inject the `Router` into my `AppComponent` constructor and then use the `unshift` function on the `router.config`. That kind of works, but I would have to store all the new routes ('users') into my database in a separate file, and then query the database every time someone navigates to a private rote ( e.g. `domain/johndoe`).

Is there a beautiful and easier to maintain solution, which takes into account my back-end configuration?

Comment: I think you would be better of creating a dynamic route like domain/:username and have a component which fetches your data from firebase and renders it. Learn more here: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Would this allow a user to navigate to domain/johndoe ?

Comment: if your users are logged in, yes. you can show a link using routerLink with a dynamic parameter.

Comment: If you read my question again , you would notice that I would want to create routing , which would be global , to say so . So in case a user in America registers as 'Lincoln' , immedaitely after a annonumous user in Europe would be able to navigate to 'domain/lincoln' . I know that is not achieveable throug only the front-end . that is why I have stated what backend I am using

Comment: You can protect your domain/lincoln route by an AuthGuard which relys on data from your backend. But are your users logged on? Its a bit hard for me to understand what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass userName as a route parameter. In routes array

```
{ path: 'domain/:username', component: UserDetailsComponent }
```

in HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/domain', usernameVar]">
```

When someone clicks on the link, it will route to UserDetailsComponent. In the component,
the username can be read.

```
username: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.username = params.username; // same as :username in route
    });
    // using username call the BE api and fetch data
}
```

for more on route parameters, go to https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters

In case you want to route to the page based on authorization, use authGuards.
https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication

Comment: I did not want to use routerLink , but to generate dynamically routes for the application , which would be accessible over it instances.

Comment: How are you planning to trigger the route, programmatically or by events?

Comment: To be honest your solution worked perfect ! Now I realized that using domain/:parameter could actually work perfect , then I just need to check in the database if such a user exists and fetch the data or navigate to a 404 page , using a route guard . Thanks